# Minimal norm problem whose unknown is an operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory

Generally given an Hilbert space $X$ with and a bounded linear operator $H : X \to X$ given a vector $y \in X$ we seek an $x \in X$ such that

$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{2} \left\lVert Hx - y \right\rVert_2^2
$$

Is minimal to calculate the Frechet differential we could calculate

$$
f(x + h) - f(x) =  \left\langle Hh, Hx - y \right\rangle + \frac{1}{2} \left\lVert Hh \right\rVert_2^2
$$

Where the differential $D[f](h) := \left\langle Hh, Hx - y \right\rangle$, to find the minimum of such functional we seek an $x \in X$ such that for all $h \in X$ we have

$$
 0 = D[f](h) := \left\langle Hh, Hx - y \right\rangle = \left\langle h, H^*Hx - H^*y \right\rangle
$$

and therefore we want to find $x$ such that

$$
H^* H x = H^* y \iff x = (H^*H)^{-1} H^* y
$$

which is the well known pseudoinverse.

Now in a problem I have instead of attempting to find $x \in X$ I am attempting to find $H \in B(X)$ given both $x, y \in X$. Now defining

$$
F(H) = \frac{1}{2} \left\lVert Hx - y \right\rVert_2^2
$$

and calculating

$$
F(H + E) - F(H) = \left\langle Ex, Hx - y \right\rangle + \frac{1}{2} \left\lVert Ex \right\rVert_2^2 := D[f][E] + \frac{1}{2} \left\lVert Ex \right\rVert_2^2
$$

the differential yields

$$
0 = D[f](E) = \left\langle Ex, Hx - y \right\rangle
$$

Which is the best characterization I can give at the moment of $H$, I wonder however:

1. Can something precise can be said about $H$, maybe characterizing it by an equation not involing $E$?
2. In addition to 1. can we say something when we know $H$ is of the form:
   $$
   H = \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n} \alpha_j T_{x_j}
   $$

where each $\alpha_j \in \mathbb{R}$ and $T_{x_j}f(x) = f(x - x_j)$ (i.e. the translation operator, assuming $X = L^2(G)$ where $G$ is some locally compact group).

Comment: I’m confused. There always exists $H$ such that $Hx = y$, as long as $x \neq 0$, doesn’t it?

Comment: I think what I am trying to work out is a formula or a procedure to construct a minimizer $H$.

Comment: As long as $x \neq 0$, $H(h) = \frac{\langle h, x \rangle}{\langle x, x \rangle} y$ gives you a minimizer. If $x = 0$ then any $H$ gives you the same result. Does this answer your question?

Comment: What is $h$? Also how did you get the formula. I don't know if it does. I think the analogue I am thninking of this problem is when you want to find a matrix $X$ such that $\left\lVert XA - B \right\rVert_F^2$ is minimal.

Comment: $H$ is an operator from $X$ to $X$, and $h$ is just its input. You can literally just plug in $Hx$ and see that it equals $y$, and therefore minimizes $F(H)$.

Comment: What if $H$ is a I've specified in 2. Your formula I don't think it works in that case.

Comment: This is also what your entire calculations with differentials would yield. $Ex$ could be any vector as long as $x \neq 0$, so saying the differential is $0$ for all $E$ just means $Hx = y$.

Comment: If you specifically want something of that form, you should specify that in your question, instead of posing that as an additional question when part 1 has a negative answer.

Comment: I changed the question to have 2. as addition

Comment: How did you get that $Hx = y$ is implied by $\left\langle Ex, Hx - y \right\rangle = 0$, I think $H(h)$ is eventually "a solution" not "all solutions".

Comment: Again, as long as $x \neq 0$, $Ex$ could be any vector (just use that $H$ I wrote down before), so if $\langle Ex, Hx - y \rangle = 0$ for all $E$ this just means $\langle h, Hx - y \rangle = 0$ for all $h \in H$, which just means $Hx - y = 0$.

Comment: I’m not sure what is unclear about any of this, quite honestly. When you’re trying to find a minimizing vector, $x \mapsto Hx$ may not be surjective, but the map $H \mapsto Hx$ is surjective, so long as $x \neq 0$. That’s all.

Comment: Let me make a comment on 2. In general there isn’t going to be a single global minimizer, since the space $Hx$ with $H$ ranging over all linear combinations of translation operators might not be closed. The best that could be said seems to be $H$ should be chosen so that $Hx$ is the orthogonal projection of $y$ onto $\overline{Ax}$ where $A$ is the algebra of linear combinations of translation operators (the left regular representation of the group algebra), if such an $H$ exist (otherwise it’s going to be a sequence of $H_n$ that minimizes the functional in the limit).

Comment: As I am assuming $H$ is finite sum of linear combination of translation operators I think the closeness is there. Am I wrong?

Comment: Is the set of finite linear combinations of the standard basis closed in $l^2$? Once you realize that it is not, then the same reasoning applies here. (In fact, this is exactly the case if, say, $G$ is infinite discrete and $x = \delta_g$ for some $g \in G$.)

Answer (score 3):

Let me try to explain the series of comments by David Gao and transform it into a complete answer. It is worth keeping in mind the types of objects here:

> The elements $x, y$ are considered to be given and fixed.
> Corresponding to $x$ and $y$ we define the functional $F:B(X) \to \mathbb{R}$ with the expression $F(H) = \frac12 \| Hx - y\|^2$.
> Our goal is to find a (all?) minimizer of $F$.

#### Case 1: $x = 0$

If the parameter $x$ is the zero element of $X$, then the expression for $F$ reduces to
$$ F(H) = \frac12 \|y\|^2 $$
which is constant. And hence **every** $H\in B(X)$ is the global minimum of $F$.

#### Case 2: $x = 0$

Observe that by definition $F(H) \geq 0$ for any $H$. Hence if we find an $H_0$ such that $F(H_0) = 0$, then $H_0$ would be a global minimum.

In order for $F(H_0) = 0$, we need to $H_0x - y = 0$. This we see that

> a sufficient condition for $H_0\in B(X)$ to be a minimizer of $F$ is that $H_0x = y$.

A particular example of one such operator is given by
$$ H_*: X \ni \xi \mapsto \frac{\langle x,\xi\rangle}{\langle x,x\rangle} y $$
(In the case where $X$ is a complex inner product space, I prefer by inner products to be linear [and not conjugate linear] in the second slot.)
In fact, if $A$ is the subset $A:= \{H\in B(X) | Hx = 0 \}$, then given any $L \in A$ we see that $H_0 = H_* + L$ is a minimizer. Similarly, given any other $H_0$ satisfying $H_0 x = y$, we find $H_0 - H_* \in A$.

Hence

> a sufficient condition for $H_0$ to be a minimizer of $F$ is that $H_0$ belongs to the affine subspace $H_* + A$ in $B(X)$.

Finally, given $H$ such that $Hx = z \neq y$, so that $F(H) > 0$. Consider now

$$ F((1-\lambda)H + \lambda H_*) = \frac12 \| (1-\lambda)z - (1-\lambda) y)\|^2 = (1-\lambda)^2 F(H) $$

This shows that $H$ cannot be even a local minimizer for $F$ (just look at all $\lambda$ small and positive).

> this shows that the requirement $H_0 \in H_* + A$ is also *necessary* for $H_0$ to be a minimizer of $F$.

---

#### The variational formula

Maybe it is worthwhile to see how this is implied by the variational formula you derived.

What you've found is that the first variation of $F$ is the assignment
$$ B(X) \ni E \mapsto \Re \langle E x, Hx - y\rangle $$
When $x = 0$, then this assignment is always zero; this agrees with our previous assessment that when $x = 0$ any $H$ is a solution.

When $x \neq 0$, given any $z \in X$ we can find $E_z : =\xi \mapsto \frac{\langle x,\xi\rangle}{\langle x,x\rangle} z$ such that $E_z x = z$.
Therefore, in order for the first variation to vanish for all $E$, it must also vanish for all $E_z$, and hence we must have that $\langle z, Hx - y\rangle = 0$ for all $z\in X$. But this implies $Hx - y = 0$, again in agreement with the analyses above.

---

#### A philosophical comment

The non uniqueness of the solution should not be surprising. Even in the case where you are solving for $x$ using the pseudo inverse, the operator $H^*H$ is in general not invertible (consider the case where $H$ has a kernel). Our situation here is similar (the act of evaluating $H\in B(X)$ at a point $x\in X$ is a linear functional of $B(X)$, with $A$ being its kernel).

The availability of $H_*$ can also be drawn in parallel to the case where one is solving for $x$: in the case where $y$ belongs to the range of $H$, then any pre-image of $y$ is obviously a minimizer of $f$; here again we are solving the equation $Hx = y$.

Comment: What about the case where $H$ is linear combination of translation operators?

Comment: @user8469759 What about it? Your question is not terribly clear. Are you intending it to be a constrained optimization problem? If so: Is $n$ fixed? Are the $x_j$ givens? If so, then this is a finite dimensional optimization problem where the optimal $\alpha_j$ can be found using calculus. If not: you are encouraged to ask a new question with this case only, making sure to spell out precisely your setting.

Comment: See this: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/467299/minimal-norm-problem-with-linear-combination-of-translation-operator-to-be-estim